# Skyrim flashing launching screen

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

My question is basically when trying to loading Skyrim via Steam, the "preparing to launch" screen flashes on and off over and over, I have tried removing all my mods, I have tried reinstalling the game completely, I have tried removing the .ini files. The only way that I am able to get the game running is by running it in offline mode. I am assuming this is an issue with Steam opposed to Skyrim!

If anyone else knows what can cause this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Try verifying game cache and deleting ClientRegistry.blob from your Steam folder.

Answer (score 1):

Steps taken from the steam support article: [Games do not run after 'Preparing to Launch'](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6218-USFX-5568)

1. Use Windows update to update your computer
2. Update your computer's drivers
3. Verify the game cache files
4. Disable any background applications (antivirus, etc.)
5. Run secondary installers manually

   - Located in separate folders in `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\` or `C:Program Files(x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\skyrim\` on a 64-bit system.

If none of this works, or you need more detail, have a look at the [Steam Support Article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6218-USFX-5568).